# Do visual basic forms each run in separate memory?

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-4.0

Do visual basic forms each run in separate memory and if not is there a way that I can force them to do so. I want them to be in separate memory so that if one form freezes the entire program won't.

Answer (score 2):

You're really asking about separate *threads* rather than separate *memory*. If you have several forms within the same application, they will usually run within the same thread. While you *can* force each window to use a different thread, that will make your life much more complicated at other times.

I would recommend that instead of trying to work around the problem of one form freezing, you simply fix it so that it *doesn't* freeze. To do that, you should avoid doing significant amounts of work on the UI thread - you should use background threads or asynchronous operations to avoid blocking the UI thread.

Comment: I'm making a Virtual OS and when people run many windows on older computers it freezes up. Also I have some full games that are very Ram Intensive because they are 3-d and may have many things on screen at once at times.

Comment: @carstorm: It really depends on what you mean by a "Virtual OS" - if you want to enforce separation, you should be using different AppDomains or even potentially different processes.

Answer (score 0):

Jon Skeet's gives you the idea but here's the specific class & code snippet to create responsive UI.

class: BackgroundWorker

code snippet: [Using BackgroundWorker class for long running processes in WPF or Silverlight](http://theludditedeveloper.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/using-the-background-worker-process-for-long-running-processes-in-wpf-and-silverlight/)